# Linguistic term for the introductory sentence preceding a list of statements

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is a linguistic term for the introductory sentence preceding a list of statements. In the example below, the clause preceding the bullet points.

A successful candidate for this position should demonstrate

- Sound judgement in complex situations
- Fairness in the treatment of others
- the ability to adapt to other discourses
- and so forth

Comment: *Linguistic* term? As in the study of languages and how they work?

Comment: I might call that a *[rubric](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rubric)* unless someone enlightened me with a better term.

Comment: @user the question (even before I edited to clarify) seems to be asking specifically for the sentence preceding the list.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a list, although you would need to change the punctuation you used to fit your items into a list (either "horizontal" or vertical). I also had to add some words to your example in order to make it grammatical.

> A successful candidate for this position should demonstrate several qualities: sound judgment in complex situations, fairness in the treatment of others, the ability to adapt to other discourses, and so forth.
>
> A successful candidate for this position should demonstrate several qualities:
>
> - sound judgement in complex situations,
> - fairness in the treatment of others,
> - the ability to adapt to other discourses,
> - and so forth.

Here are four resources that discuss the use of colons with lists (although some vertical lists can be styled without colons).

> Use a colon before a list when the list is preceded by a complete independent clause. ([English Plus](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000096.htm))
>
> If the initial clause cannot stand alone and make complete sense, you should not use a colon. ([The University of Bristol](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_04.htm))
>
> The colon may be used between two independent clauses not joined by a conjunction if the second clause explains, illustrates or enlarges upon the first. ([Public Works and Government Services Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-srch?lang=eng&srchtxt=colon&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0))
>
> The most important thing to remember about colons is that you only use them after statements that are complete sentences. Never use a colon after a sentence fragment.  . . . The rules are the same whether you are writing lists or sentences: use a colon when you could use the word *namely* and after something that could be a complete sentence on its own. ([Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/colons))

Based on this, and using grammar terminology, an "introductory sentence" preceding a list is just an *independent clause*. (And the reason I added *several qualities* to your example was because it was only a sentence fragment without it.)

Outside of this, I've also heard "introductory sentences" called "lead-ins" in plain English.